# abundance of numbers in an array/c++

Tags: c++

How can I write a program to iterate over an `int` array of size 10 and output how many times each integer inside the array appears without outputting the same integer more than once.
The array is filled with 10 random `int`s between 1 and 10, **but the program should be written as if the programmer doesn't know that**.
Using another array or changing the values of the given array is forbidden.
Using `std::map` is also forbidden. 
For example :

```
int arr[10] = {2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4};
```

Should output

```
0:1(abundance)

1:1

2:2 

3:1

4:1

5:2

6:1

9:1
```

Comment: If your array is arr then in python 3 just write   for i in arr: print (arr.count(i))

Comment: @AbhishekYadav in c++ not python

Comment: I assume you can use nested loops if the output is required to be sorted. I also assume you are not permitted to use std::map<int,int> which is not an array but its usage would make the problem trivial.

Comment: @drescherjm yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you may not use any kind of containers, the only way I can think of is this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    const size_t SZ = 10;
    const int arr[SZ] = { 2, 2, 3, 5, 9, 1, 0, 5, 6, 4 };
    int max = arr[0];
    for(auto e : arr){
        if (e > max){
            max=e;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= max; ++i){
        size_t cnt = 0;
        for (auto e : arr){
            if (i == e){
                ++cnt;
            }
        }
        if (cnt){
            std::cout << i << " : " << cnt << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is not very efficient, but with the restrictions you have, i cannot think of a better way.

output:

```
0 : 1
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 1
4 : 1
5 : 2
6 : 1
9 : 1
```